# grouped bar graph with different background style in react

Tags: reactjs, bar-chart, svg-filters, react-chartjs, grouped-bar-chart

Is there anyway we can create grouped bar graph like this in react, using library or SVG.[image: In the image it has only bar but it can have multiple bars.]

I was able to create graphs with SVG but have no idea how to create that neumorphic background effect in SVG.